# How do you add options to the Right Click Context Menu when nothing is selected in Finder in OSx Mojave?

Tags: macos, applescript, contextmenu, automator, macos-mojave

I am wondering if it's possible to modify the Context Menu which pops up when you right-click on nothing in particular in Finder (shown below on the right-hand side)

I have no trouble adding options to the context menu which pops when you right click an item (left-hand side)... but is there a way to add options to the menu on the right-hand side?

For instance, could I add a custom option 'New Majig' below 'New Folder'?

[image: Context Menu Comparison]

**Further Info:**

In case it's useful, here's how I'm creating the options I want to use:

1. I created my custom options in **Automator > Quick Action**, like so:

[image: Creating Service in Automator]

2. And then I added them to the context menu in **System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services**

[image: Adding Services to Context Menu]

**Details:**

I am in Mojave 10.14.2

Comment: Short answer: No, it's not possible, as far as I know.  Longer answer: It is possible with some Swift or Objective-C programming if you fancy creating your own _Finder_ app/plugin.

Comment: Seems like a Finder bug. For the system-provided contextual menu items, when you've right-clicked on an empty part of the folder content area, they act on the folder that the window represents. For example, the Get Info item in your Right Click on Nothing image will show the info for the folder containing "em.txt" and "example". In my opinion, the Finder should show the same contextual menu items that it would if you were to right-click that folder's icon (as it would appear in its containing folder's window).

Comment: @KenThomases I agree that that is how it _ought_ to work, but there are examples where _Finder_ hasn't done that for as long as I can recall.  For example, the _Services_ contextual menu doesn't appear in High Sierra and earlier versions if you right-click an empty selection, even though it would make sense given that services can run on the folders that contain files.  I'd say it's much less a bug (i.e. not something _Finder_ is designed to do, but doesn't), and just a design flaw.

Comment: Sure, but maybe worth filing a bug report with Apple to prod them to fix the design. :)

Answer (score 1):

Something cool you can do nowadays is add it to the menubar:

1. Open Shorcuts app
2. Choose Menu Bar, click on + to add an action
3. Select run shell script
4. `touch ~/Desktop/newfile`
5. Or if you want the txt extension use: `touch ~/Desktop/newfile.txt`
6. Name the shortcut as New File

Result:

[image: clicking that will create a file in your desktop]

Answer (score 0):

***Hello, it is possible to add context menu without applescript or any language, just by using XtraFinder.app and setting context menu options. It's not a devellopement or programming response, but it works.***

Comment: JSYK While XtraFinder does add some additional commands to the context menu nonetheless, **it does not allow the user to add their own user defined or created commands**, only that which is already a part of XtraFinder. Therefore IMO and sans the fact that this answer states "... but it works.", it does not work within the context of what the OP explained. Additionally, according to its website this software may or may not work properly once SIP is reenabled. - Under Mojave, it's still beta software and you must have at least 2 items on the Desktop for it to work, otherwise it won't even load.

Comment: Bravo, very good answer deek5, XtraFinder.app allows to add in the context menu of Finder options, even when you just click on the desktop, we can add 5 types of file, it works under Mojave without problems. If the subject is not to add the creation of new file, do not hesitate to search all the options of XtraFinder.app. A focus of Finder of a very high quality.